# Get parameters from URL with ampersand

Tags: html, itunes, http-get

Question: How to properly get the parameters from a URL with ampersand symbols?

Context:
I'm trying to figure out why is it the result from **[iTunes Store Webservice](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching)** returns different data when removing **amp;**. I'm using this diff tool: https://www.diffnow.com/compare-urls

Original URL:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&amp;country=au&amp;media=movie&amp;all
```

What's more confusing to me is the ***all*** value in the url. Based on the doc of [iTunes Store Webservice](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching), it's either an `attribute` or `entity`.

But regardless, I still get different result. To reiterate,

the original url:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&amp;country=au&amp;media=movie&amp;all
```

returns different data for the following:

```
a. https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&amp;country=au&amp;media=movie&amp;attribute=all
b. https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&amp;country=au&amp;media=movie&amp;entity=all
c. https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&country=au&media=movie&all
```

Comment: What languages are involved?

Comment: I guess any, my mere purpose of this question is to clear my confusion. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a small helper and use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor to get an object representing the URL defined by the parameters.

From this object, we're going to get the [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search) property that it's the *query string* and replace the `&amp;` to `&`.

```
function getItunesParameters(url) {
  const { search } = new URL(url);
  const parsedQuery = search.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

  return parsedQuery;
}

getItunesParameters('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&amp;country=au&amp;media=movie&amp;all');
// => "?term=star&country=au&media=movie&all"
```

Optionally you can return an object if it's easy for you to handle afterwards

```
function getItunesParameters(url) {
  const { search } = new URL(url);
  const parsedQuery = search.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

  return parsedQuery
    .slice(1)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((acc, query) => {
      const [key, value] = query.split('=');
      return { ...acc, [key]: value || '' };
    }, {});
}

getItunesParameters('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=star&amp;country=au&amp;media=movie&amp;all'); //?
// => {term: "star", country: "au", media: "movie", all: ""}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this does not answer my confusion. Are you saying that replacing `&amp;` with `&` will give same result?

Comment: Once again the language would determine how to go about it because each has different capabilities.

Comment: @EternalHour Language won't matter I think, you can every do try this in your browser. Now I'm thinking they actually yield same result BUT different arrangement. I can select Indgalante's answer as an answer if there will be no better answers.

Comment: @Glenn so you receive `&amp;` and other times the `&` right?

Comment: No. I was just confused. I got an online assessment test that says I should use such URL and nothing else. I just wanted to make sure I get the correct results.